# Jupyter Notebool: Error in "Head" unix command in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: unix, jupyter-notebook

While running unix command Head in Jupyter notebook,

% head -n 3 $filename

I am getting below error:
ERROR:root:Line magic function %head not found.

[JupyterNote Book Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUCJP.png)

Answer (score 0):

are you actually typing `% head` if yes then remove `%` and run again.

Comment: On changing code as:    head -n 5 $filename    Iam getting following error:  File "<ipython-input-18-5bcda18e63c0>", line 1
    head -n 5 $filename
            ^`
SyntaxError: invalid syntax